# How to pass parameters when importing a module that provides JSON data?

Tags: javascript

If I have something like,

```
// resources.js
import DB from 'some/massive.json';

export const RESOURCES = (() => {
  const {
    dataA,
    dataB
  } = DB;

  return [
    dataA,
    dataB
  ];
})
```

And I import it like

```
// someOtherFile.js
import { RESOURCES } from 'path/to/resources.js'
```

How can I import `RESOURCES`, passing in parameters, so as to limit the data that is received? `RESOURCES` could be MB in size, and I don't need all of them for each test that runs, I just need specific resources for specific tests.

Something like,

```
import DB from 'some/massive.json';

export const RESOURCES = (dataToExclude = null, () => {
  const {
    dataA,
    dataB
  } = DB;

  const dataArray = [
    dataA, dataB
  ].flatMap(data => {
    // Process
    return data;
  })

  // dataArray will look something like,
  // [ { dataName: 'NameA', ...props }, { dataName: 'NameB', ...props } ]
  if (dataToExclude) {
    const indexToSplice = dataArray.findIndex(({ dataName }) => dataName === dataToExclude)
    dataArray.splice(indexToSplice, 1)
  }

  return dataToExclude;
});
```

Comment: What are `dataName` and `props` in `dataToExclude`? What is the structure of `DB.dataA` and `DB.dataB`? Why are you returning `dataToExclude` rather than `dataArray`?

Comment: Why supply data to **exclude** rather than data to **include**?

Comment: Well, `dataName` could be `'NameA'`, it doesn't matter. The body of `RESOURCES` isn't the question, I'm just asking to see if it's possible to pass in parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The body of RESOURCES isn't the question, I'm just asking to see if it's possible to pass in parameters

Your `RESOURCES` is **already** a function, there's no need to wrap it in another function. (There's also no reason to wrap it in parens, though they're harmless.) Pass it the filtering criteria you want it to have:

```
export const RESOURCES = (filteringCriteria) => {
  const {
    dataA,
    dataB
  } = DB;

  // ...apply filtering here...

  return [
    dataA,
    dataB
  ];
};
```

...then call it after importing it:

```
const data = RESOURCES({/*...filtering criteria...*/});
```

But **if** you want to wrap it in another function, yes, you can do that and have the inner function close over the filtering criteria:

```
export const RESOURCES = (filteringCriteria) => {
  return () => {
      const {
        dataA,
        dataB
      } = DB;

      // ...apply filtering here...

      return [
        dataA,
        dataB
      ];
  };
};
```

Then you'd call it once to establish the filtering criteria, and call the result of that to actually get the data:

```
const dataSupplier = RESOURCES({/*...filtering criteria...*/});
// ...
const data = dataSupplier();
```

Comment: I see. So what if `RESOURCES` is an IIFE? Is it still possible to pass in filtering criteria as it is imported?

Comment: @MikeK - It would depend on what you mean by *"...`RESOURCES` is an IIFE..."*. An IIFE, by its nature, is usually transient (unless you play games inside it to save a reference somewhere) and you store the result of calling it, not the function itself. But re passing parameters when importing: you can't pass any parameters when importing something with `import`. To pass filtering criteria, you'd need to import a function and then call it.